# Laravel Some Error: htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, php-7

After deciding several problems in project i have the last problem.
At last question, I've said that i'm not PHP/Laravel developer but i need to support some project and add some fixture.
And I need community help :)

app.blade.php

```php
    <!-- OpenGraph -->
    <meta property="og:title" content="{{isset($og_title) ? $og_title : "MARVEL" }}" />
    <meta property="og:type" content="{{isset($og_type) ? $og_type : ''}}" />
    <meta property="og:url" content="<?php echo "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]" ?>" />
    <meta property="og:description" content="{{isset($og_description) ? $og_description : ''}}" />
    <meta property="og:image" content="{{isset($og_image) ? $og_image : ''}}" />
```

database

```sql
mysql> SELECT og_image FROM heroes;;
+-----------------------------------------+
| og_image                                |
+-----------------------------------------+
| uploads/images/uWXGUnrZU6cHAZXyPQvT.png |
| NULL                                    |
| NULL                                    |
| NULL                                    |
```

How i can fixture this?
And this og_image will be not only in one model Hero
For example.

---

For more information.
Task: I need to take url from uploaded og_image

Thanks!

Comment: What is the exact issue? Can you provide your stack trace? Which line exactly causes the problem? Also it seems that `content="{{isset($og_title) ? $og_title : "MARVEL" }}"` might not work since you use `"` inside of `"` you should put `'MARVEL'` instead of `"MARVEL"` there.

Comment: @Frank, problem caused by og_image line

Comment: Use $heroes->og_image

Comment: @OkaforTKosiso - the problem is that i use og_image in 4 models, and they will be different in app.blade when client render different pages.

Comment: closed - the answer was simple
$og_image->value